# vectorizing integral function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization, curve-fitting, numerical-integration

I have the following function in Matlab:

```
function y = exact_func(q0,x)
q = q0/(1+x^2);
h_func = @(t) sech(t).^2;
fun = @(t) log(1+q*h_func(t));
y = integral(fun,-Inf,Inf)/(q*integral(h_func,-Inf,Inf));
end
```

It accepts the position `x` and the parameter `q0` and returns a scalar. How can I modify the function so that it can accept an array for `x` (a series of steps)? Ultimately, I want to fit this function to some data (to find the best fitted `q0`, but then Matlab complains about matrix dimensions not agreeing, so I think that's because my current version of the function only accepts scalar `x`, not vector `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set [`'ArrayValued'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#btw3ipp-6) property to `true` for `integral` of an array valued function. Also there are some mistakes where you need to use [element-wise operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html). See the fixed code below:

```
q = q0 ./ (1 + x.^2);    
%       ↑       ↑     You need to use element-wise operations as indicated 
h_func = @(t) sech(t).^2;
fun = @(t) log(1 + q*h_func(t)); %---↓------↓ 
y = integral(fun,-Inf,Inf,'ArrayValued',1) ./ (q*integral(h_func,-Inf,Inf));
```